# how can we get popup by touching on particular image i n android?? code will be better help for me

Tags: android

how can we get popup by touching on particular image and popup should be cancel by moving out from image in android?? code will be better help for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageViewName>.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==0)//0-ACTION_DOWN
             {
                Toast.makeText(<Current Activity>.this, "Image is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else
                 if(event.getAction()==1)//0-ACTION_UP
                 {

                 }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Through the above code we can display a pop up msg.In my code i am display a simple message.

Comment: thank you praveena this is the code for what i was looking for...thanks once again....

Comment: and please my ques again i have edited it...and give me response..thanks